# NodeJS, Webpack, Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am new to web development and just finished my first [assisted project](https://github.com/ReactjsProgram/react-fundamentals-curriculum/tree/step10) using Webpack and React. I am trying to move from the development environment used in the project to production by creating my own NodeJS server rather than using Webpack-dev-server.

Here is my code:

**webpack.production.config.js**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

var config = {
  devtool: 'source-map',  
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "index_bundle.js",
    publicPath: __dirname + '/dist'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
      {test: /\.(png|svg|ico)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "file?name=img/img-[hash:6].[ext]"}
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}

module.exports = config;
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "weather-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config  webpack.production.config.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "start -p": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/img'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/dist/index_bundle.js'));

app.get('*', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(5578, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

and **index.html** produced in my /dist folder after calling

> NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Weather App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    html, body, .app {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app" class='app'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/cwelch/Code/weather-app/dist/index_bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

After calling

> node server.js

When I navigate to http://localhost:5578/ I receive this error in the console

> index_bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I cannot figure out why this is happening. I am suspicious of an error in my JSX compilation with Babel as well as an error in my server.js.

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this? Also, can anyone point me to a reading covering moving from a development to production environment? I want to get my first website live with AWS or Google Cloud, but I can't seem to find the guidance I need.

**UPDATE**

The publicPath variable in my webpack config file is what was messing me up. I removed that line as well as the source map since I do not think I need it for production.

Comment: so sad that you never got an answer.

Comment: I had the same issue and It was in fact the publicPath :) thanks